# How to only update a Backbone view if the collection changed on the server?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, view, polling

I've got a page  for which I poll for notifications. If there are any notifications I populate a [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) view with the notifications. I currently poll for notifications every 2 seconds and simply repopulate the view every two seconds.

```
function updateNotificationView(ticketId) {
    var ticketNotificationCollection = new TicketNotificationCollection([], {id: ticketId});
    $.when(ticketNotificationCollection.fetch()).done(function() {
        var notificationView = new NotificationsView({collection: ticketNotificationCollection});
        $('#ticket-notifications-area').html(notificationView.render().el);
    });
}
window.notificationsIntervalId = setInterval(function() {updateNotificationView(ticketId);}, 2000);
```

I now want to only populate the view if the Backbone fetched collection has changed, but I have no idea how I could do that?

Could anybody give me a tip on how I could only populate the view on collection change? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
I now changed the function to this:

```
function updateNotificationView(ticketId) {
    var ticketNotificationCollection = new TicketNotificationCollection([], {id: ticketId});
    var notificationsView = new NotificationsView();
    notificationsView.listenTo(ticketNotificationCollection, 'change', notificationsView.render);
    notificationsView.listenTo(ticketNotificationCollection, 'add', notificationsView.render);
    ticketNotificationCollection.fetch();
}
```

and I changed the NotificationsView to this:

```
var NotificationsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    addNotificationView: function(notification) {
        var singleNotificationView = new SingleNotificationView({model: notification});
        this.$el.append(singleNotificationView.render().el);
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('ITS BEING CALLED!!');
        this.collection.each(this.addNotificationView, this);
        $('#ticket-notifications-area').html(this);
    }
});
```

I now get the "ITS BEING CALLED!!" in the console every two seconds, but also an error:
"*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined.*". I get why this error occurs; its because the collection is never actually inserted into the view. I don't get however, how I can solve this.. Any more tips?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are getting models in the collection in response to your request as JSON.

**Method 1:**

You can simply set the collection to the JSON. and bind the collection to `change` event. In case of any change in the collection, callback function will be triggered. In the callback function you can render your view.

Note: `change` event on collection will be triggered only if there is any change in the models it contain.

e.g.

```
someCollection.on('change', function(){
    someView.render()
  });
```

**Method 2:**

You can use Backbone's [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) method, to render the view on change of collection.

```
someView.listenTo(someCollection, 'change', someView.render);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks Shubhansh, I'm slowly starting to make more sense out of Backbone. I used your second method, but I can't get it to work. Could you check out my edited question? It would be really awesome if I get this to work..

Comment: Try with these changes 1. In updateNotificationView function, write line 2 as last line of function. 2. Put console.log('called') in render function to check if it is getting called. 3. Bind to 'add' event as well as you do for 'change'.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I get another step further, but not fully there yet. I now get an error saying: "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined.*". I edited my initial question again (replacing my previous edit). Would you have any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Unfortunately I now get `Cannot read property 'models' of undefined.`. It seems that even though it reacts to changes in ticketNotificationCollection, it doesn't get that collection in the render method. Would you know how I can get the collection into the render method?

Comment: You don't have collection defined for view, that's why you are getting this error

Comment: Ehmm, any idea how I could do that? As you can see I'm a beginner with Backbone.. :|

Comment: In your edit, you miss passing the collection to your `NotificationsView`. Try changing that line back to `new NotificationsView({ collection: ticketNotificationCollection });`